# Android - Camera2 : "Unknow Error" the second time

Tags: android, release, android-camera2

I use the Camera2 object to take a photo.
It works like a charm the first time, but I receive an "Unknow Error" (through the OnErrorListener) the second time.

My question is : Do I need to close/release manually the CameraDevice after **onConfigured** ? :

```
public void onConfigured(CameraCaptureSession cameraCaptureSession) {
    try {
        CaptureRequest.Builder requestBuilder = cameraDevice.createCaptureRequest(CameraDevice.TEMPLATE_STILL_CAPTURE);
        requestBuilder.addTarget(imageReader.getSurface());
        requestBuilder.set(CaptureRequest.CONTROL_AF_MODE, CaptureRequest.CONTROL_AF_MODE_CONTINUOUS_PICTURE);
        cameraCaptureSession.capture(requestBuilder.build(), null, null);

    } catch (CameraAccessException exception) {
        exception.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: Always, release/close resources after finishing, including `onConfigured`.

Comment: @t0mm13b Indeed thanks! You solved this problem. However, curiously the "onImageAvailable" is fired occasionally. Why's that?

Comment: Unregister any listeners prior release/close resources.